# Page curl effect using ios7 Sprite Kit

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, page-curl

I am developing a kid's book based on iOS7 Sprite Kit. The book has music and animations as well as some interactive stuff going on, that's the reason for using Sprite Kit.

I've been looking around this issue: creating the curl page effect.

[iOS documentation says:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/ContentViews.html)
Page View Controller

A page view controller manages multipage content using either a scrolling or page-curl transition style.

In iOS 7, use the pageViewControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and pageViewControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations methods to specify preferred and supported orientations, respectively.

But that's for ViewControllers, what about a SKScene?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but this might help http://www.raywenderlich.com/56858/how-to-create-an-interactive-childrens-book-for-the-ipad

Comment: Thanks @Smick, I already read that web. Unfortunatelly it does not say how to implement the page curl effect.

Comment: http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/